# Dynamically Adding Row With Dropdown Ajax Calls in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

[Add DropDown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIHZg.jpg)

[image: Screenshot of the view]

In the above image i am populating dynamically row with the following code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
var $button = $('#add-row'),
$row  =$('tr.timesheet-row').clone();
$button.click(function() {
$row.clone(true).appendTo('tbody').val("");
});
});
```

Now i want to whenever i add rows the test name will be changed according to test category selected by user via a ajax call but i am facing a problem that only the first row is changed via ajax call but rest or not.
Now the code for ajax call is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  // function myAjaxFunction(elem)
   //{   
       $('.changeAjax').change(function() {
       var selTestCatg = $(this).val();
       $.ajax({  
                url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/addPatientDetails/selectTestName",
                type: "POST",
                data: "testCategory="+selTestCatg,
                success: function(data){
                  $('#testName').html(data);
                }
            });
     });
   //}
 });
</script>
```

This is my view portion

```
<tbody>
                        <tr class="timesheet-row">
                            <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
                            <!--<td><input type="text" data-type="doctorName" name="doctorName[]" id="doctorName_1" 
                                 class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>-->
                            <td>
                              <select name="doctorName[]" id="doctorName" class="form-control autocomplete_txt">
                                <option selected="selected" value="">Select Doctor Name</option>
                                 <?php 
                                   foreach($listDoctor as $row1)
                                   {
                                 ?>
                                    <option value="<?= $row1['id'] ?>"><?= $row1['name'] ?></option>
                                 <?php
                                   }
                                 ?>
                              </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <select name="testCatg[]" id="testCatg" class="form-control changeAjax">
                               <option selected="selected" value="">Select Test Type</option>
                               <?php 
                                 foreach($listTestType as $row2)
                                 {
                               ?>
                                  <option value="<?= $row2['id'] ?>"><?= $row2['test_type'] ?></option>
                               <?php
                                 }
                               ?>
                              </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><!--<input type="text" name="testName[]" id="testName" class="form-control changesNo" 
                                 autocomplete="off" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">-->
                                 <select name="testName[]" id="testName" class="form-control autocomplete_txt">
                                  <option selected="selected" value="">Select Test Name</option>
                                 </select>
                                 </td>
                            <td><input type="number" name="testPrice[]" id="testPrice_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice"
                                 autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" onpaste="return false;" value=""></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

This is my Database Portion:

```
public function getTestName()
    {
      $this->db->select('test_details.*,test_catg.test_type as TestCategory');
      $this->db->from('test_details');  
      $this->db->join('test_catg','test_catg.id = test_details.test_catg_id');
      //$this->db->where('test_details.test_catg_id',$testCatgID);
      $query3 = $this->db->get();

      if($query3->num_rows() > 0)
      {
        $result3 = $query3->result_array();
        return $result3;  
      } 
      else
      {
        return FALSE;  
      }
    }
```

This is my Controller Portion:

```
public function selectTestName()
    {
      $testCatgID = $this->input->post('testCategory');
      if(isset($testCatgID) != '')
      {
        $listTestName = $this->patientDB->getTestName($testCatgID);
        foreach($listTestName as $row3)
        {
          $testName .= '<option value="'.$row3['id'].'">'.$row3['test_name'].'</option>';   
        }
        echo $testName;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Change:   var selTestCatg = $(this).val(); to --> var selTestCatg = $("option:selected",this).val();

Comment: I want that after adding each row from add row button in the above image according to my change in test category drop down test name dropdown will be change via an ajax call but it's only working for the first row not for the rest of the rows added later via add more button click.

Comment: what is the error ??

Comment: After adding each rows the ajax is not working from the second row